LUA ERROR i can't find the malicious endpoint
I'm working on my Gmod DarkRP server and I have the following error.
[ERROR] Attempted request to known malicious code endpoint 'https://kvac.cz/f.php?key=ZEhWgVuEB4ZMnSPCH0dl'! Blocking!
  1. Fetch - lua/includes/modules/http.lua:42
   2. unknown - DRME:1

But I can't find the malicious endpoint in the different addon that I have.
Does anyone have an idea where I can find it ?
I try to find it using the search tool of visual studio code

Is "lua/includes/modules/http.lua" a file somewhere on your computer? If so, that's where the error is getting thrown. Figure out why it's trying to access https://kvac.cz/f.php?key=ZEhWgVuEB4ZMnSPCH0dl and make it stop doing that. Beyond that, we can't give you much specific advice without a [mre], which you should [edit] your question to include.

That's not a Lua error btw.

Your first step is to reliably reproduce the issue.

How often does this error occur?
What steps can you perform to make the error occur?

E.g. does this happen every time you start up and join your server?
Then, you should remove addons from your server to work out which addon is causing it.

Run the server without any addons

No addons from the workshop and no addons in the server's addons folder
If you no longer get the error, go to step 2
If you still get the error

The problem could be within the server's files; a fresh install of the server would be best (backup your config and any custom content)
The problem could be within your copy of the game (I believe DarkRP allows custom clientside lua to execute); you will either need a fresh install or you will need to search your addons, lua and download folders




Run the server with some of the addons

You could keep re-adding one addon until you get the error again
Once you start getting the error again, the last addon you added will be the source of it
If you have a lot of addons, you could try re-adding multiple addons until you get the error. Then removing one addon at a time until the error stops happening. Or using a divide and conquer approach.



